Remove error backtrace from laravel lighthouse response
I am using laravel lighthouse framework for GraphQL API, and I am trying to return error to the user.
How can I remove "locations" and "path" from the response? (I want to have "errors" with only "message" and "data").
For example:
public function doSomething($_, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo){
    $apples_count = $context->user()->apples;
    if(apples_count > 10){
      //do something
        return  [
            'success' => true
        ];
    }else{
        throw new Error('You must have more then 10 apples');
    }
}

If user will have less then 10 apples, this should be returned:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "You must have more then 10 apples",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "doSomething"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "doSomething": null
  }
}

I have tried the following but I'm still not getting the error in the intended format:

Created my own exception
Changed APP_DEBUG=false and APP_ENV=production
Added LIGHTHOUSE_DEBUG=null|false|0


This question is similar to: can I throw custom error in laravel-lighthouse. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for response @Airah, and I wrote in my question that this is copy of that question. But solutions from there didn't help me. That's why I created similar question, and want to find working solution. Please, read my question fully.

Then you can either edit the previous question to seek further guidance or delete it and keep this one
